# SQLiteDatabase insert method

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I'm having issues inserting rows into my database. When I trigger insertEntry() through my activity class, database.insert(...) returns 1 which should mean that there were no issues. Nothing is actually being saved though! As soon as a re-load the database, it's like I never inserted anything.

Activity Class

```
...
MyDBHelper myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
myDBHelper.open();
myDBHelper.insertEntry(str, num);
myDBHelper.close();
```

MyDBHelper Class

```
// Here I have "database" defined as a private SQLiteDatabase object.
public void insertEntry(String str, int num)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("myStr", str);
    values.put("myNum", num);
    database.insert("myTable", null, values);
}
```

In my SQLiteHelper Class, I open the db using OPEN_READWRITE, so it should be writable.

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you know that it is returning 1 when you're not checking it anywhere?

Comment: I did this, but I took it out
Log.w("databaseinsert: ", "" + database.insert("myTable", null, values));

Comment: Do not use hard-coded paths. Android defines a directory for each app to store it's databases. You should use `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your database and use its `getWriteableDatabase()` method to obtain a database object.

Comment: Do you drop your table when opening the database? Do you have transactions you don't set as successful? Also, consider using just plain `SQLiteOpenHelper` instead of rolling the error prone `openDataBase()` and such in there.

Answer (score 0):

There's some mistake that you're doing somewhere. Probably in your `MyDBHelper` class. Try this code and it should work fine:

```
public void insertEntry(String str, int num)
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("myStr", str);
    values.put("myNum", num);
    long rowID = database.insert("myTable", null, values);
    Log.i("", "Newly inserted row id: " + rowID);
    database.close();
}
```